# Como fazer classes com funções multi-nivel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um código para o seguinte problema:
Eu tenho uma série de experimentos a serem feitas. Para cada experimento, tenho que fazer diferentes cálculos (que eu chamei de beta, dinâmico e estático no exemplo abaixo) e plotar diferentes gráficos.

Naturalmente, eu pensei em fazer algo assim:

```
class experiment:
    
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        
    def beta(self):
        
        def calculate(self):
            
            return self.a+self.b
        
        def plot(self):
            pass
        
    def static(self):
        
        def calculate(self):
            
            return self.a+self.b+self.c
        
        def plot(self):
            pass
        
    def dinamic(self):
        
        def calculate(self):
            
            return self.a+self.b*self.c
        
        def plot(self):
            pass
```

Meu objetivo é que fosse possível chamar a função com um comando do tipo `exp.beta.calculate()` e `exp.dinamic.plot()`, por exemplo, mas não está funcionando como eu queria. Dessa forma como eu fiz dá os seguintes erros:

```
teste.beta.calculate()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'calculate'

teste.beta().calculate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'calculate'
```

A dúvida é: como que eu faço para conseguir escrever códigos que tenham múltiplos níveis como esses que eu estou tentando?

P.S.: Eu já tentei fazer usando herança múltipla mas também não funciona do jeito que eu pretendo, pois eu teria que ficar instanciando o mesmo experimento várias vezes.

P.P.S.: Desculpe se o título ficou inapropriado, mas é que eu não tenho ideia do "nome técnico" para essa dúvida.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou reproduzindo tudo que está no seu exemplo, mas acho que dá para ter uma ideia.

### Definindo Beta

```
>>> class Beta:
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...     def calculate(self):
...         return self.a + self.b
```

### Definindo Experiment

```
>>> class Experiment:
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...         self.c = c
...         self.beta = Beta(self.a, self.b)
...
```

### Executando

```
>>> e = Experiment(1,2,3)

>>> e.beta.calculate()
3
```

Comment: era exatamente isso que eu queria. Muito obrigado!